# Anchor tag not responding to full width of button

Tags: html, css, button, anchor, nav

The buttons on my side menu aren't responding to the cursor on the right side. I've checked through some of the answers with similar questions and played around with solutions but nothing seems to be working. You can view the HTML below:

```css
  div.nav-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  height: 160;
  width: 235;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 160px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 3;
}

nav .menu-tab {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  //opacity: .4;}
  nav p {
    position: relative;
    top: 2%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;
    left: -10%;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  nav li {
    margin: 7px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  nav .hli {
    background-color: rgb(0, 88, 237);
  }
  nav .sli {
    background-color: rgb(53, 255, 0);
  }
  nav .mli {
    background-color: rgb(255, 235, 0);
  }
  nav .cli {
    background-color: rgb(255, 179, 84);
  }
  nav a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  nav a.ha:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 88, 237);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  nav a.sa:hover {
    color: rgb(53, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  nav a.ma:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 235, 0);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  nav a.ca:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 179, 84);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrap">
  <nav>
    <div class="menu-tab"><i class="fa fa-paw" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <p><u>Menu</u></p>
    <ul>
      <li class="hli"><a class="ha" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li class="sli"><a class="sa" href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="mli"><a class="ma" href="#membership">Membership</a></li>
      <li class="cli"><a class="ca" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I've tried to display the anchor as a block, and as an inline-block with a specified width and even modified the padding for the anchor tags but nothing seems to be working. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the cursor won't respond to the full width of the anchor tag?

Comment: @KarthikTsaliki — What's wrong with putting it here?

Comment: Now it is fine good edit.

Comment: You should specify a unit, for instance pixels, when declaring width and height on div.nav-wrap

Comment: At least in the snippet here it appears to be working fine; the cursor, hover, and links all work no matter where on the buttons I click.  Is it possible you have something else in your page that might be partially overlapping this menu and preventing clicks from reaching it?

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: @DanielBeck Thank YOU! That's definitely a noob mistake. I do have another div box with the company's title overlapping the menu! Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, happens to all of us from time to time. Glad I could help.

Comment: @agrm Thanks! I usually do specify the unit. I make sure to catch that next time.